# Paypal Rest API on sandbox doesn't return shipping address after execute

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

We are using Paypal rest api to process payment on your site. After successfully `Payment::execute`, I receive the payment information (with state approved) and when I dump the `$payment->getPayer()` I get the following

```
object(PayPal\Api\PayerInfo)[949]
  private '_propMap' (PayPal\Common\PPModel) => 
    array (size=4)
      'email' => string 'paypal-buyer@example.com' (length=23)
      'first_name' => string 'Buyer' (length=5)
      'last_name' => string 'Buyer' (length=5)
      'payer_id' => string 'XXXXXXXXXXX' (length=13)
```

as you can see there is no shipping address. is this a limitation of the REST api?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we do not currently return the shipping address of a buyer unless a shipping address was passed in the initial `/payment` request made by you (which means that, obviously, you would already have the shipping address).

We're adding functionality to return the shipping address in other scenarios in the future, though I don't have a fixed date for this for you.

Comment: I managed to capture the shipping address from IPN data. I don't if it is a good practice though.